# Returning Dictionary<string,?> from LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

I haave a LINQ to SQL query whose final `select` is this:

```
 select new{
                id = <result id>,
                serial = <result serial>,
                type = <result type>,
                model = <result model>
        }
```

After this, I would like to group my result locally.
I need an output JSON like this:

```
[   
    {
        "id":group_id, 
        "data":[
                {...},
                {...}
               ]
    }
]
```

So far, I've managed to do something like this:

```
var res = q.ToList();
var dict = res.GroupBy(m => m.machine).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

and then I serialize it with

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);
```

But I'm pretty sure I'm doing it all wrong.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The fact that my output is very far from what I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply an `Array` or `List`? Your *JSON* looks like an array of object, You can project an *anonymous* type like this:-

```
var result = res.GroupBy(m => m.id)
                .Select(x => new 
                           {
                               id = x.Key,
                               data = x.ToArray()
                           }).ToArray();
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I need! The only thing is... How can I not replicate "id" value in "data"?